# Retrieving the active component and path

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

With Angular2, how would I retrieve the current active component and path?

For example I might have the following routes:

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'list', component: ListComponent },
{ path: ':id/', component: CustomComponent }
```

If I had navigated to `https://domain.com/test` is there a way to know I'm currently viewing the `CustomComponent` and to retrieve the id/path, which in this case is "test"?

I could use `window.location.pathname` with regex to get the path but this is messy and still doesn't allow me to easily get the active component.

Comment: Could you expand on the context - what's the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: Sure. I need to get the path for use with an API but it must be while the user is viewing `CustomComponent` as I'm not interested in the other route paths such as "list". I only want the custom "id".

Comment: Then did you read the docs? This is covered in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can check current active component using router snapshot-

```
import { Router,ActivatedRoute }      from '@angular/router';

constructor(public route : ActivatedRoute) {
    var snapshot = route.snapshot;
    console.log(snapshot._routeConfig.component.name); //This will give you the name of current active component
  }
```

Note- **snapshot._routeConfig.component.name** it will give you the active component name, and if you want url you can also get it by .url instead of name

Comment: Just noting for future people looking that it looks like `_routeConfig` has been renamed to `routeConfig`

Answer (score 4):

In `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` the `component` property is defined as being one of the following

```
component: Type<any> | string | null;
```

So you can't just do `component.name` unless you've already made sure you have `Type<any>`. This is because `.name` on a string doesn't exist.

Now `Type<any>` is actually a function that creates the type (your component type) and is defined as:

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

So you can do something like this, which will actually compile

```
 if (typeof(this.route.snapshot.component) === 'function')
 {
     // the compiler is 'smart' enough to know that component here must be Type<T>
     const name = this.route.snapshot.component.name;
 }
```

An 'elegant' way to do it is using a typescript typeguard (although to be frank in this case it doesn't give you much of a benefit over what I just said).

```
isComponent(item: Type<any> | string | null): item is Type<any>
{
    return typeof item === 'function';
}
```

Then you can say `this.name = isComponent(this.route.snapshot.component) ? this.route.snapshot.component : null`.

**Important:**
`component.name` is still valid in an AOT build, but unfortunately with `--prod` it will end up being something random like `r`.

I've resorted to having to inject `private element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>` and then look for the tag name. This will still be present even with an AOT prod build. There may be a performance cost to doing this so cache it if you're using it a lot.

```
    if (element.nativeElement.tagName.startsWith('RR-')){
        super.name = element.nativeElement.tagName;
    }
```

Comment: Only the ElementRef option works with production build.

Comment: For those looking down this road, please see @Simon_Weaver's "Important" note. If you are trying to run a switch based on active component name, for example, it will die in production.

Answer (score 1):

you can enable trace in your router config for root `{enableTracing: true}` to get more idea how routes are resolved and activated

Answer (score 0):

Yah, the angular 2 starter guide covers all that, basically you need to inject ActivatedRoute on your component then you can retrieve the information you want by subscribing to the route params.

I would really recommend you to do the angular tutorial tour of heroes, it is actually pretty good learning material that they provided.

Inject ActivatedRoute, on your component constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params['id']);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using `ActivatedRoute`module you can access route parameters or bind to parameters cgange event

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";

constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
}

this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params['id']);
});
```

Also here you can also access your current component type using

```
this.activatedRoute.component;
```