# Lazy loading get current routed module

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I am trying to exclude a component if a certain module has been routed in a lazy loading application.

For example in my AppComponent i am using router-outlet and above a component:

```
<div>
    <my-component></my-component>   --> don't show if module is StartModule
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My routing configuration looks like following:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'start',
    loadChildren: './start/start.module#StartModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'first',
    loadChildren: './first/first.module#FirstModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'second',
    loadChildren: './second/second.module#SecondModule'
  }
];
```

Is there a parameter to receive the routed module to make a check like

```
isStartModule(): boolean {
    if (routedModule == StartModule) {
        return true; 
    }
}
```

`<my-component *ngIf="!isStartModule()"></my-component>`

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580495/retrieving-the-active-component-and-path

Comment: Import Router from @angular/router, check current route like this: this.router.url == 'start' ... check against the path url not the module name.

Answer (score 4):

```
constructor(private router: Router ) {}
```

try to check

```
this.router.url === '/start'
```

then do something

---

2. You can sucscribe to event

   ```
    this.router.events.pipe(
       filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
       .subscribe(x => {
           console.log('THIS IS FOR TEST', x['url']);
           }
       );
   ```

Comment: You can --->  import Router from @angular/router

Answer (score 0):

You can set a route change listener in your app-component like this:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
constructor(private router: Router)
{
  router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd) ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {    
    console.log(event.url);
    if(event.url == 'start'){
    // do you stuff
    }
});}
```