# Angular 8 shows TS2339 error, but code works fine and I am getting correct output

Tags: angular, typescript

I get Error as

> ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts:13:37 - error TS2339: Property
>   'name' does not exist on type 'string | Type'.   Property 'name'
>   does not exist on type 'string'.
>
> 13       this.pageName=route.component.name;

but my code work fine. it only gives me issue while building the code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.sass']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
pageName;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router) { 
  this.pageName=route.component.name;
}
ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

> I tried changing ES version too. doesn't help

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51833622/2050306

Comment: You need to specify type for the property `pageName` (eg: pageName: string;).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what the provided [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51833622/2050306) says, you can use the [Route's data](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) property, to feed your components with route-specific custom data.

`data`:

> Additional developer-defined data provided to the component via ActivatedRoute. By default, no additional data is passed.

The developer-defined data is also the safe and practical way, because after the application is created (for production) the class names are given an arbitrary name, so you should not rely on it.

Example:

**Routing config**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  // ...
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
      page: 'Home Page',
      class: 'super-sweet-home',
      color: 'blue',
      // ....
    },
  }
];
```

**Consuming the data**

- Solution 1: Within a component, e.g. `HomeComponent`.

```js
private subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.route.data.subscribe((data: any) => { 
        /* data will be provided after navigation ends successfully */ 
    });
}
```

- Solution 2: Via [Router events](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) using a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services), e.g. `SiteService`

```js
public readonly currentPageData = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private router: Router) {
this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd))
  .subscribe(event => {
    this.currentPageData.next((event as ActivationEnd).snapshot.data as any);
  });
}
```

Within a component, you can then inject the service and subscribe for the `currentPageData` of the `SiteService`, e.g.:

```js
constructor(private siteService: SiteService) {
    this.siteService.currentPageData.subscribe((data) => {
      /* data data data */
    });
}
```

Last but not least: don't forget to [unsubscribe the subscriptions](https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/).

Comment: Though it was not what i asked for , but upvoting for teaching me something new